# Trying set property from page cookie to chrome extension HTML i have undefined state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just started learn JS. I can't resolve issue with "undefined" state of cookie trying get cookie variable from page and display it in extension

I have HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h1 id="userID"></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
    "browser_action": {
        "defaul_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "premissions": [
        "cookies",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

And JS:

```
      function getCookie(name){
    let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
      "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined
  }
  window.onload = function(){
    let userid = getCookie("WebChartingUser");
    let element = document.getElementById("userID");
    element.innerHTML = userid;
  }
```

But I always have "undefined" state. So what's the problem?

Comment: What is `undefined`?

Comment: Have you tried to see what `decodeURIComponent(matches[1])` returns?

Comment: Ye I have, it returns - string